# How to detect decimal in a String in Smarty?

Tags: preg-match, smarty, preg-match-all

For example, if I have a String variable

```
 $someString = "The price is 35.12 Thank you"
```

I want the $result to be 35.12
How can I do that in a Smarty Template? thanks

Below is my code

```
 {if preg_match('/\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/', $someString , $result)}
      The result is {$result}
 {else}
      no decimal found!
 {/if}
```

Comment: I think the classical `{$someString|regex_replace:'/[^\d.]+/':''}` will do here.

Comment: It's not a task for template, you should do it in application.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh thanks, that works too